# How to remove the colored indent area guide in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How I can remove this area guide in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: To be fair, the question is not about the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That does not look like the built-in indent guides of VS Code.

That looks like you have the [indent-rainbow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow) extension installed:

*(screenshot from extension page)*
[image: indent-rainbow screenshot]

Just disable or uninstall the extension.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to mute the extension, so that you see more traditional indent guides. In settings (currently) you have `classic` and `light` indicator styles. Choose the `light` style. Also consider adding an entry to exclude all file types from highlighting errors (which will show up in some shade of red colorization otherwise).

###### Classic style (default):

[image]

###### Light style:

[image]

###### Note:

Both of these settings can be added to your settings.json. Typically it is easy to work with the GUI version of the settings editor in VSCode, but in some cases (like the ignoreErrorLanguages) you may have to edit the settings in settings.json directly:

```
"indentRainbow.indicatorStyle": "light",
"indentRainbow.ignoreErrorLanguages": [
    "*",
],
```