# The margins in my VS Code became colorful, how can I remove this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, editor

Suddenly, the margins in the my VS Code editor became colorful. No matter which theme I apply, it's same for all. I don't know how this happened.

This is a reference image of the colored margins:

[image: This is a reference image of the colored margins]

How do I remove this and make it transparent?

Comment: that is the action of one of your extensions

Comment: why does the screenshot of your desktop not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the colored indent area guide in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222375/how-to-remove-the-colored-indent-area-guide-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably coming from the [`oderwat.indent-rainbow`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow) (or some other) extension. You can either change your settings to change how the extension displays, or go to the extensions sidebar and disable the extension.

Comment: Yes, resolved, thank you very much 